# Reflection - restore time.Time instance

Tags: reflection, go

I am developing a program in go that needs to store and retrieve an array of custom structure instances using the `sessions` package of the Gorilla toolkit. For restoring the custom structure I need to make use of reflection features. The issue is that my structure named `Timestamp` includes two `time.Time` instances and I have not been able to restore the instances. Thus, my question is how to restore a `time.Time` instance.

Below you can see my code for the `Timespan` structure as well as the code for storing and reading the `Timespan` array in the session store.

```
type Timespan struct {
    ID uint8;
    StartDate time.Time;
    EndDate time.Time;
}

func (server *WebServer) setTimespans(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request, timespans [model.TimespanCount]*model.Timespan) error {
    var session *sessions.Session;
    var sessionDecodingException error;
    session, sessionDecodingException = server.SessionStore.Get(request, authenticationSessionName);
    if sessionDecodingException != nil {
        return sessionDecodingException;
    }


    session.Values[sessionTimestamps] = timespans;
    return nil;
}

func (server *WebServer) getTimespans(request *http.Request) ([model.TimespanCount]*model.Timespan, error) {
    var session *sessions.Session;
    var sessionDecodingException error;
    session, sessionDecodingException = server.SessionStore.Get(request, authenticationSessionName);
    var readTimespans [model.TimespanCount]*model.Timespan;
    if sessionDecodingException != nil {
        return readTimespans, sessionDecodingException;
    }

    interfaceValue := reflect.ValueOf(session.Values[sessionTimestamps]);
    var actuallyAddedTimespan *model.Timespan;
    for counter := 0; counter < model.TimespanCount; counter++ {
        actuallyAddedTimespan = &model.Timespan{};
        actuallyReflectedTimespan := interfaceValue.Index(counter).Elem();
        actuallyAddedTimespan.ID = uint8(actuallyReflectedTimespan.FieldByName("ID").Uint());
        //actuallyAddedTimespan.StartDate = actuallyReflectedTimespan.FieldByName("StartDate");
        //actuallyAddedTimespan.EndDate = actuallyReflectedTimespan.FieldByName("EndDate");
        fmt.Println(actuallyAddedTimespan);
    }
    return readTimespans, nil;
}
```

Comment: IMHO stop coding Go like Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the interface to the field:

```
actuallyAddedTimespan.StartDate = actuallyReflectedTimespan.FieldByName("StartDate").Interface().(time.Time)
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/TB74mLATUt)

Personal opinion time, using reflection for this rather than using a simple interface is:

1. Slow.
2. Inefficient
3. Can break easily if you change how your struct looks and forget to update the reflection code.

Example of using an interface:

```
func main() {
    ts := &Timespan{ID: 102, StartDate: time.Now().AddDate(6, 0, 0), EndDate: time.Now().AddDate(8, 0, 0)}
    m := map[string]interface{}{
        "key": ts,
    }
    switch v := m["key"].(type) {
    case Timespaner:
        fmt.Println(v.Value())
    default:
        fmt.Println("wtfmate?")
    }
}

func (ts *Timespan) Value() (id uint8, start, end time.Time) {
    return ts.ID, ts.StartDate, ts.EndDate
}

type Timespaner interface {
    Value() (id uint8, start, end time.Time)
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/iCo_xXq4JC)

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I do not really understand what you mean by using a simple interface instead of reflection. I would be most graceful if you could explain this a little.

Comment: @Lukas I added an interface example, it's just to give you a general idea, generally reflection should be avoided except for things like JSON/XML marshaling/unmarshaling.

Comment: Thank you for the interface example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Interface()` function to get the `interface{}` value from a struct. Then, you can use a type assertion to get the correct type back:

```
func main() {
    t := &Timespan{42, time.Now(), time.Now()}
    reflectedPointer := reflect.ValueOf(t)
    reflectedTimespan := reflectedPointer.Elem()
    var timespan Timespan = reflectedTimespan.Interface().(Timespan)
    fmt.Println(*t)
    fmt.Println(timespan)
}
```